# How do I replace a substring by the output of a shell command with sed, awk or such?

Tags: perl, awk, sed, pattern-matching

I'd like to use `sed` or any command line tool to replace parts of lines by the output of shell commands. For example:

- Replace linux epochs by human-readable timestamps, by calling `date`
- Replace hexa dumps of a specific protocol packets by their decoded counterparts, by calling an in-house decoder

`sed` seems best fitted because it allows to match patterns and reformat other things too, like moving bits of matches around, but is not mandatory.

Here is a simplified example:

```
echo "timestamp = 1234567890" | sed "s/timestamp = \(.*\)/timestamp = $(date -u --d @\1 "+%Y-%m-%d %T")/g"
```

Of course, the `$(...)` thing does not work. As far as I understand, that's for environment variables.

So what would the proper syntax be? Is `sed` recommended in this case ? I've spent several hours searching... Is `sed` even capable of this ? Are there other tools better suited?

**Edit**

I need...

- Pattern matching. The log is full of other things, so I need to be able to pinpoint the strings I want to replace based on context (text before and after, on the same line). This excludes column-position-based matching like `awk '{$3`...
- In-place replacement, so that the reste of the line, "Timestamp = " or whatever, remains unchanged. This exclused sed's 'e' command.

Comment: Awk, Perl or, Python would probably be better suited if you have more than just a few lines of `sed`. They are more versatile and much more readable.

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102504/replace-strings-with-evaluated-string-based-on-matched-group-elegant-way-not-u

Answer (score 4):

To run an external command in `sed` you need to use `e`. See an example:

```
$ echo "timestamp = 1234567890" | sed "s#timestamp = \(.*\)#date -u --d @\1 "\+\%Y"#e"
2009
```

With the full format:

```
$ sed "s#timestamp = \(.*\)#echo timestamp; date -u --d @\1 '\+\%Y-\%m-\%d \%T'#e" <<< "timestamp = 1234567890"
timestamp
2009-02-13 23:31:30
```

This catches the timestamp and converts it into `+%Y` format.

From [`man sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command):

> **e**
>
> This command allows one to pipe input from a shell command into
>   pattern space. If a substitution was made, the command that is found
>   in pattern space is executed and pattern space is replaced with its
>   output. A trailing newline is suppressed; results are undefined if the
>   command to be executed contains a nul character. This is a GNU sed
>   extension.

---

However, you see it is a bit "ugly". Depending on what you want to do, you'd better use a regular `while` loop to fetch the values and then use `date` normally. For example, if the file is like:

```
timestamp = 1234567890
```

Then you can say:

```
while IFS="=" read -r a b
do
  echo "$b"
done < file
```

this will make you have `$b` as the timestamp and then you can perform a `date ...`.

Comment: wrong documentation reference, use https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command instead

Comment: The problem is, the whole line is replaced by the output of the command. I'd like just the timestamp to be replaced (or the hexa by its decoded value), as sed usually does.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks! I had to adapt it only little to cover only lines with timestamps, e.g. #1606748699:

cat ~/.bash_history | sed "s/^#\([0-9]\+\)$/echo -n '#'; date -u --d @\1 '\+\%Y-\%m-\%d \%T'/e" | less

Answer (score 2):

As commented, use a language with built-in time functions. For example:

```
$ echo "timestamp = 1234567890" | gawk '{$3 = strftime("%F %T", $3)} 1'
timestamp = 2009-02-13 18:31:30

$ echo "timestamp = 1234567890" | perl -MTime::Piece -pe 's/(\d+)/ localtime($1)->strftime("%F %T") /e'
timestamp = 2009-02-13 18:31:30
```